# LZ4 decompression using python

Tags: python-3.x, redis, lz4

I compressed the data using lz4 java library (https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java) and want to decompress it in python using lz4 library(https://pypi.org/project/lz4/). And the compressed data is available in redis cluster. When I execute the following code:

```
    from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster
    startup_nodes = [{"host": "my_host", "port": "7002"}]
    rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=False)
    result=rc.hget("key","field")
    from lz4.frame import compress, decompress
    decompress(result)
```

I am getting the error:"LZ4F_getFrameInfo failed with code: ERROR_frameType_unknown

What am I doing wrong?
"

Comment: seems like a miss use of the lz4 library and not a redis issue

Comment: replaced lz4.frame with lz4.block. The data gets decompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. You can see the following link if you are facing the same problem:

https://github.com/python-lz4/python-lz4/issues/143

Comment: Nitika - I tried to do the same but I could not get the decompression working. Can you tell me your java code that you are using to compress? I took it from here -> https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java